# FlatList Android Items Overlepping

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, overlapping

I have a FlatList in my ReactNative app, but I noticed (when alternating background colors) that the items are overlapping one another in a small space.

An Example of how overlapping it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHfLD.jpg

My Styles, basically changing colors (in the rows).

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tableRow: {
        padding: 5,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
    },

    tableBuy: {
        backgroundColor: colors.buyBackground
    },

    tableSell: {
        backgroundColor: colors.sellBackground
    },
})

export default styles;
```

My Component TSX

```js
export default class CoinPageHistoryComponent extends React.Component<CoinPageHistoryProps> {
    constructor(props: CoinPageHistoryProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    renderHistoryBlock = ({ item }) =>
        <View style={[styles.tableRow, item.type === "SELL" ? styles.tableSell : styles.tableBuy]} >
            <Text style={styles.tableRowItem1} >{item.type === "SELL" ? "+" : "-"} {item.quantity.toFixed(8)}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.tableRowItem2} >{item.rate.toFixed(8)}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.tableRowItem3} >{item.total.toFixed(8)}</Text>
        </View>

    public render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.tableRow}>
                    <Text style={styles.tableRowItemHeader} >Quantity</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.tableRowItemHeader} >Rate</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.tableRowItemHeader} >Total</Text>
                </View>

                <FlatList
                    style={styles.table}
                    data={this.props.coin.history}
                    keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
                    onRefresh={() => this.props.onRefresh()}
                    refreshing={this.props.refreshing}
                    renderItem={this.renderHistoryBlock}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part does it overlap?

Comment: In the print (link) you can see some white lines between the lines. Above this blank lines are a darker line (where the items overlap and it "sum" the colors, making it darker).

Comment: where is `styles.table`?

Comment: Just a { flex: 1 }

Comment: Try removing `flex:1` from `styles.tableRowItem1`

Comment: IT did not help. It was fixed. Almost a "gambiarra" (type of bad work around in Portuguese). Putting a transparent border magically killed the problem. :)